# In PHP,implementing a two dimensional array

Tags: php

For example I have a two dimensional array...

```
a[0][1]=x
a[0][2]=y
a[0][3]=z
........................

a[1][1]=a
a[1][2]=b
a[1][3]=z
..........................
```

I want x,y data in blue colour
I want a,b data in green colour
I want z to data to be in voilet colour.....How will i do this in php
Can anyone explain this with an examplle
I have similar work,in a complex structure...This fundamental wil help me ..Can anyone guide

Comment: I want a pony and a better explanation to your question

Comment: @Gordon your wish is my command. http://www.grugapark.de/ponyhof.html

Comment: @Gordon yeah, and even parrots! Nice.

Comment: The example, the explanation and the solution needed are all vague, if not contradicting each other.

Comment: I am sorry if i am not clear....Imagine x y z as some data like name age and occupation....I want this data to be displayed in the specified colour.How wil I do that?

Comment: @Gordon nice! But here's one for sale not too far away.  http://www.kalaydo.de/iad/marktplatz/tiere/lewitzer-pony-zu-verkaufen-/anzeige/?kalaydonr=12240029 Isn't she sweet.

Comment: @Sreeja - can you show us what you've tried so far, the code you've used

Comment: @Sreeja you will need to add the colour information somewhere. You could do that in a separate array for example.  `$colors[1] = "blue";`

Comment: @Sreeja is the second level always refering to the same datum? E.g. is [n][1] always refering to age, [n][2] always refering to name and [n][3] always refering to occupation? In other words, is it always [20,'John','Farmer'], [30,'Jane','Secretary'] and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to generate HTML with differently colored text. Learn about <span> tags and CSS colors.